Plotting a 4D graph where X,Y,Z are independent and the fourth dimension is a heatmap that interpolates between points
I have been trying to plot a 4d heat map, where my X,Y,Z components are coordinates and thus independent of one another. I then want to map a fourth component onto each coordinate, and represent its relative intensities as a heatmap. I then want to interpolate between all points to produce a contour/gradient.
This would be using real data, where I have measured the temperature of a liquid in a cup. For now I am using just plan numbers I made up, but I need to be using discrete numbers.
Below is my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

### INTENSITY VALUES FOR HEATMAP (TEMPERATURES) ###
#Center
fdr1 = 1,2,3,2,1
#Inner cylinder
fdr11 = 2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2
#Middle cylinder
fdr21 = 3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3
#Outer cylinder
fdr31 = 4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4

###CO-ORDINATES###
a=0
b=0
rO = 7.5
rM = 5
rI = 2.5
heights =  1,2,3,4,5

#6 radial points
O = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,7)

Xs = []
for j in O:
  xx = a+rO*np.cos(j)
  Xs.append(xx)
Xs1 = []
for j in O:
  xx = a+rM*np.cos(j)
  Xs1.append(xx)
Xs2 = []
for j in O:
  xx = a+rI*np.cos(j)
  Xs2.append(xx)

Ys = []
for k in O:
  yy = b+rO*np.sin(k)
  Ys.append(yy)
Ys1 = []
for k in O:
  yy = b+rM*np.sin(k)
  Ys1.append(yy)
Ys2 = []
for k in O:
  yy = b+rI*np.sin(k)
  Ys2.append(yy)

Coords = []
for i in heights:
  ptsA = (0,0,i)
  ptsB = (Xs[0],Ys[0],i)
  ptsC = (Xs[1],Ys[1],i)
  ptsD = (Xs[2],Ys[2],i) 
  ptsE = (Xs[3],Ys[3],i)
  ptsF = (Xs[4],Ys[4],i)
  ptsG = (Xs[5],Ys[5],i)
  CoordsO.append(ptsA)
  CoordsO.append(ptsB)  
  CoordsO.append(ptsC)
  CoordsO.append(ptsD)
  CoordsO.append(ptsE)
  CoordsO.append(ptsF)
  CoordsO.append(ptsG)

Coords1 = []
for i in heights:
  ptsB = (Xs1[0],Ys1[0],i)
  ptsC = (Xs1[1],Ys1[1],i)
  ptsD = (Xs1[2],Ys1[2],i) 
  ptsE = (Xs1[3],Ys1[3],i)
  ptsF = (Xs1[4],Ys1[4],i)
  ptsG = (Xs1[5],Ys1[5],i)
  Coords1.append(ptsB)
  Coords1.append(ptsC)
  Coords1.append(ptsD)
  Coords1.append(ptsE)
  Coords1.append(ptsF)
  Coords1.append(ptsG)

Coords2 = []
for i in heights:
  ptsB = (Xs2[0],Ys2[0],i)
  ptsC = (Xs2[1],Ys2[1],i)
  ptsD = (Xs2[2],Ys2[2],i) 
  ptsE = (Xs2[3],Ys2[3],i)
  ptsF = (Xs2[4],Ys2[4],i)
  ptsG = (Xs2[5],Ys2[5],i)
  Coords2.append(ptsB)
  Coords2.append(ptsC)
  Coords2.append(ptsD)
  Coords2.append(ptsE)
  Coords2.append(ptsF)
  Coords2.append(ptsG)

CoordsOT = np.transpose(CoordsO)
CoordsMT = np.transpose(Coords1)
CoordsIT = np.transpose(Coords2)

XSO,YSO,ZSO = CoordsOT
XSM,YSM,ZSM = CoordsMT
XSI,YSI,ZSI = CoordsIT

###Heat Map###
grad = 'coolwarm'

mB = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=grid)

cA = fdr11
fAcolors = mB.to_rgba(cA)

cB = fdr21
fAcolors = mB.to_rgba(cA)

cC = fdr31
fAcolors = mB.to_rgba(cA)

def data_for_cylinder(center_x,center_y,radius,height_z):
  z = np.linspace(0,height_z,50)
  theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
  theta_grid, z_grid = np.meshgrid(theta,z)
  x_grid = radius*np.cos(theta_grid) + center_x
  y_grid = radius*np.sin(theta_grid) + center_y
  return x_grid,y_grid,z_grid

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15), dpi=300
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d'

fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(0,1),cmap=grad),
  ax=ax,orientation='vertical')
Xo,Yo,Zo = data_for_cylinder(0,0,7.5,5)
Xm,Ym,Zm = data_for_cylinder(0,0,5,5)
Xi,Yi,Zi = data_for_cylinder(0,0,2.5,5)
ax.plot_surface(Xo,Yo,Zo,alpha=0.05)
ax.plot_surface(Xm,Ym,Zm,alpha=0.05)
ax.plot_surface(Xi,Yi,Zi,alpha=0.05)
ax.scatter(XSO,YSO,ZSO,facecolors=fAcolors,marker='o',s=200,edgecolors='black')
ax.scatter(XSM,YSM,ZSM,facecolors=fBcolors,marker='o',s=200,edgecolors='black')
ax.scatter(XSI,YSI,ZSI,facecolors=fCcolors,marker='o',s=200,edgecolors='black')

plt.show()

This produces:
enter image description here
As you can see, it plots 3 sets of data as cylinders, however the heatmapping doesn't really work, and I am lost on how to interpolate these points. If anyone has an insights, or a completely different way to visualize this data please let me know.
I have successfully plotted the 3d data into cylinders on my plot. I have also plotted the intensities to each of these points, however I have noticed that the heatmap is not one that joints all three data sets, which means it is wrong. I couldn't figure out how to make one heatmap/colors apply to all three data sets so that it normalized to the min and max of all three.
I cannot figure out at all how to interpolate between these points. I am at a loss.

If the intent is to communicate these data with others then I think it is doomed to fail. You would be better off showing 2-D slices through representative axes of symmetry.  That is how tomography does it for voxel images. Also make the tags for each cylinder different and if you can scale their size to give some illusion of perspective and distance (and shift the starting phase for each cylinder point set). The vertical line down the centre axis is incomprehensible.

So that was what I was thinking too. However I wanted to make the 3d (4d) plot, and then take "slices" of it to show a 2d heatmap. Maybe I am being too redundant in this approach, since I agree this 3d graph is difficult to read. Do you have any links of how people do it in tomography that would be useful as a start for me?

Sorry forgot to @MartinBrown

The one most likely to work best for you as a quick look see for a voxel image is probably the 2D x-y slice shown for equally spaced z in a grid pattern - like this example of a human brain.

@MartinBrown sorry I meant if you had any good resources that you can recommend for programming voxel images in python. I have been searching but I've found it difficult to know where to start.
